# FIWARE Cepheus generic configuration

Tags: fiware-orion, complex-event-processing

I plan to use Cepheus to allow users to create relationships between Orion entities.
The problem is that there is only one configuration file. So it makes it hard to create several CEP (within the same tenant).
For example, say I want to create the average temperature for the floor, and also close the shutters (see examples http://fiware-cepheus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/2_CloseShutters/index.html).

Is it possible/reasonable to subscribe all entities/attributes in the config file?
i.e.

```
{
     "idPattern": "*",
     "typePattern": "*",
     "attributes": [{ "name":"*" }]
 }
```

So the users will only have to create statements (instead of the full structure).

I would also be nice to have a CRUD API to manage each statement separately :)
Final question, I plan to use CEPHEUS in a Cloud platform (not in the gateway), alongside with Fiware Orion. Is it a reasonable use case?

Answer (score 0):

Each entity and its attributes must be described (properly typed) to allow Cepheus to map an NGSI entity to Esper CEP internal data model which must *know* the types of the `events` and their attributes it handles at statement compilation time.

Yes, Cepheus should be able to work in a hosted environment alongside Fiware Orion.

No CRUD API was initially added as the Cepheus component is seen a leaf component of the Fiware IoT ecosystem at the gateway level where multiple instances of the Cepheus CEP would receive identical configurations push from a central management system.

It was envisioned that each configuration of Cepheus instances should themselves be hosted as NGSI entities on the Fiware Orion broker. Each instance receiving configuration updates using the pub/sub mechanism of NGSI v1.

Did you check on [Perseo Core](https://github.com/telefonicaid/perseo-core) ? A similar project embedding Esper CEP with a [CRUD API](https://github.com/telefonicaid/perseo-core/blob/master/documentation/api.md).

Comment: Maybe I can create a wrapper around CEPHEUS that will launch a new instance for each new rule posted? I checked PERSEO, the problem is that it has no link to Orion. So I'll be obliged to create that link myself.

Comment: It's not clear which is the CEP engine advised for Orion... On the catalog there is a third CEP engine, Proton. https://catalogue.fiware.org/enablers/complex-event-processing-cep-proactive-technology-online